# Generate JSON Schema from Java object

Tags: java, json

I need to generate JSON schema from Java Class, I am using Jackson Mapper to generate the same.
below is java code -

```
private static String getJsonSchema(Class clazz) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING, true);

    JsonSchema schema = mapper.generateJsonSchema(clazz);

    return mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(schema);
}
```

and my I have two entity classes one is Employee.java -

```
class Employee
{
    private Long id;
    private List<Profile> profiles;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the profiles
     */

    public List<Profile> getProfiles() {
        return profiles;
    }

    /**
     * @param profiles the profiles to set
     */
    public void setProfiles(List<Profile> profiles) {
        this.profiles = profiles;
    }
}
```

and the other is Profile.java

```
public class Profile
{
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String value;

    /**
     * @return the name
    */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the value
     */
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * @param value the value to set
     */
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the address
     */
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    /**
     * @param address the address to set
     */
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

And the generated JSON Schema is -

```js
{
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "id" : {
      "type" : "number"
    },
    "profiles" : {
      "type" : "array",
      "items" : {
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
          "id" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "name" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "address" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "value" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this is getting generated by my application, but i need the schema with "required" true or false. so is there any way out we can achieve this either by some annotations or any other thing.
the desired format which i want looks like bit similar to this -

```js
    {
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "id" : {
      "type" : "number"
    },
    "profiles" : {
      "type" : "array",
      "items" : {
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
          "id" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "name" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "address" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "value" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        },
      "required": ["id", "name", "address"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please suggest me if it is possible.

Comment: Where in your Java classes are these three members markes as `required`?

Comment: Can you please suggest me how can I mark any field as required? i tried in reverse way, i took the json schema with required array and generated the java class but i did not see any difference in java class. It is same as if I generate without required array.

Answer (score 0):

try to use mbknor-jackson-jsonschema
https://github.com/mbknor/mbknor-jackson-jsonSchema

```
// A standard validation @NotNull annotation.
@NotNull
public String foo;

// Using the Jackson @JsonProperty annotation, specifying the attribute as required.
@JsonProperty(required = true)
public String bar;
```